# How to always drop element at first position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI to connect lists so I can sort elements from one to another list. Only problem I have is that I don't know how to always drop element at the first position, no matter where I drag. If I drag from one list to another, I want that element to be at first position in that list.

I have already set up everything and I've created jsfiddle file.

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/nvyztwku/14/

```
<div class="flex">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="column">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="sortable2" class="column">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

$( function() {
    $('.column').sortable({
      connectWith: '.column'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sortable's stop event and then prepend:

```
$(function() {
  $('.column').sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.item).prependTo($(ui.item).parent())
    }
  });
  $("#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li").disableSelection();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x2h64e9c/)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/nvyztwku/28/ 

this is great but one more thing is left, I have a first child(header) that I want always to be in first position and then after each first child in list i want to drop element

Comment: You can try `$(ui.item).parent().children().first().after($(ui.item))` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4j1gvkd5/3/. BTW, including vital details like that in your original question are important